# F# print all element from the list one by one using recursion

Tags: f#

Imagine that I have function `printList` that takes list as an argument and prints all the elements in the list one by one in a new row followed by the position in the list also while having space between them.

E.G

```
1: 4
2: 9
3: 12
```

How can I implement this in F# using recursion without any built-in features ?

I assume it might look something like this, but I've problems with `int, unit` types.

```
let rec printList l = function
    match l with
    | [] -> 0
    | head::tail -> // something
```

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but it looks like you are mixing up two pattern matching constructs. You should consult the documentation on [match expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two advices I can give you so you can implement the `printList` function:

- you will have to make `printList` a non-recursive function and define a local recursive helper function in order to keep track of the index of the value.
- all branches of your `match` expression must return the same type and here what you want is the [`unit` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/unit-type).

In case you are still stuck, I provide the solution below.

---

### Solution

```
let printList list =
  let rec helper index list =
    match list with
    | [] -> ()
    | head :: tail ->
      printfn "%d: %A" index head
      helper (index + 1) tail

  helper 1 list
```

Comment: Is this tail-recursive ? If it is, is this still considered as a recursion ?

Comment: Yes, the solution is tail-recursive. As it names implies, it's still recursion but what's interesting about tail-recursive function is the compiler or runtime (depending on the language) can optimize the recursion away by replacing it with a loop, which is much more efficient.